# Woocommerce Edit order on admin dashboard

Tags: woocommerce

With Woocommerce, in Admin order edit pages, is there a way to move the post code on the second line?

Like in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Is that needed just for one specific country or for all countries?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec it is for all countries, that the Post Code need to be separated and display below, not inline with the City.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will allow you to change the display of the formatted billing and shipping address on Woocommerce admin single order (edit) pages **for all countries**:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_localisation_address_formats', 'admin_localisation_address_formats', 50, 1 );
function admin_localisation_address_formats( $address_formats ){
    if( is_admin() ){
        $address_formats = array();

        $countries = array('default', 'AU', 'AT', 'BE', 'CA', 'CH', 'CL', 'CN', 'CZ',
        'DE', 'EE', 'FI', 'DK', 'FR', 'HK', 'HU', 'IN', 'IS', 'IT', 'JP', 'TW', 'LI',
        'NL', 'NZ', 'NO', 'PL', 'PT', 'SK', 'SI', 'ES', 'SE', 'TR', 'US', 'VN' );

        foreach( $countries as $country_code ) {
            $address_formats[$country_code] = "{company}\n{name}\n{address_1} {address_2} {postcode}\n{city} {state}\n{country}";
        }
    }
    return $address_formats;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]