# Add custom billing data to billing formatted address in Woocommerce admin orders

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

With Woocommerce, I would like see user meta data in admin order edit pages using `woocommerce_localisation_address_formats` hook.

Based on *"[Woocommerce Edit order on admin dashboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52980638/woocommerce-edit-order-on-admin-dashboard/52982609#52982609)"* answer code, that I have lightly changed as follow:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_localisation_address_formats', 'admin_localisation_address_formats', 50, 1 );
function admin_localisation_address_formats( $address_formats ){
    if( is_admin() ){
        $address_formats = array();

        $countries = array('default', 'AU', 'AT', 'BE', 'CA', 'CH', 'CL', 'CN', 'CZ',
        'DE', 'EE', 'FI', 'DK', 'FR', 'HK', 'HU', 'IN', 'IS', 'IT', 'JP', 'TW', 'LI',
        'NL', 'NZ', 'NO', 'PL', 'PT', 'SK', 'SI', 'ES', 'SE', 'TR', 'US', 'VN' );

        foreach( $countries as $country_code ) {
            $address_formats[$country_code] = "{company}\n{name}\n{address_1} {address_2} {postcode}\n{city} {state}\n{country}\n{billing_nombrecontacto}";
        }
    }
    return $address_formats;
}
```

Where `{billing_nombrecontacto}` should be custom data to insert in admin order pages… But it doesn't make anything.

To add a `billing_nombrecontacto` I have used the following code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'custom_woocommerce_billing_fields');
function custom_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields,$fields2)
{
    $fields['billing_nombrecontacto'] = array(
        'label' => __('Nombre de contacto', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('Nombre de contacto', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required' => false, // if field is required or not
        'clear' => false, // add clear or not
        'type' => 'text', // add field type
        'class' => array('my-css')    // add class name

    );

    $fields['billing_cuit'] = array(
        'label' => __('CUIT', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('CUIT', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required' => false, // if field is required or not
        'clear' => false, // add clear or not
        'type' => 'text', // add field type
        'class' => array('my-css')    // add class name

    );

    $fields['billing_emaildelvendedor'] = array(
        'label' => __('Email del Contacto', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('email del Vendedor', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'required' => false, // if field is required or not
        'clear' => false, // add clear or not
        'type' => 'text', // add field type
        'class' => array('my-css')    // add class name

    );

    $fields['billing_nombrecontacto']['priority'] = 102;

    return  $fields;
}
```

The data is collected correctly, I can see it in my account for this custom field.

How to make it work? I am stuck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** *Added an additional missing function displaying the `billing_nombrecontacto` field value…*

I have revisited your existing code and added some more code to make it work:

```
// Add / Display additional billing fields in checkout and My account > Edit adresses > Billing form
add_filter( 'woocommerce_billing_fields', 'additional_billing_fields', 10, 1 );
function additional_billing_fields( $fields )
{
    $fields['billing_nombrecontacto'] = array(
        'type'        => 'text', // add field type
        'label'       => __('Nombre de contacto', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('Nombre de contacto', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'class'       => array('my-css'), // add class name
        'required'    => false, // if field is required or not
        'clear'       => false, // add clear or not
        'priority'    => 102,    // define the priority
    );

    $fields['billing_cuit'] = array(
        'type'        => 'text', // add field type
        'label'       => __('CUIT', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('CUIT', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'class'       => array('my-css'), // add class name
        'required'    => false, // if field is required or not
        'clear'       => false, // add clear or not

    );

    $fields['billing_emaildelvendedor'] = array(
        'type'        => 'text', // add field type
        'label'       => __('Email del Contacto', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field label
        'placeholder' => _x('email del Vendedor', 'placeholder', 'woocommerce'), // Add custom field placeholder
        'class'       => array('my-css'),  // add class name
        'required'    => false, // if field is required or not
        'clear'       => false, // add clear or not

    );

    return  $fields;
}

// Adding custom placeholder to woocommerce formatted billing address only on Backend
add_filter( 'woocommerce_localisation_address_formats', 'admin_localisation_address_formats', 50, 1 );
function admin_localisation_address_formats( $address_formats ){
    // Only in backend (Admin)
    if( is_admin() ) {
        foreach( $address_formats as $country_code => $address_format ) {
            $address_formats[$country_code] .= "\n{nombrecontacto}";
        }
    }
    return $address_formats;
}

// Custom placeholder replacement to woocommerce formatted billing address
add_filter( 'woocommerce_formatted_address_replacements', 'custom_formatted_address_replacements', 10, 2 );
function custom_formatted_address_replacements( $replacements, $args  ) {
    $replacements['{nombrecontacto}'] = ! empty($args['nombrecontacto'])  ? $args['nombrecontacto'] : '';

    return $replacements;
}

// Get the field values to be displayed in admin Order edit pages
add_filter('woocommerce_order_formatted_billing_address', 'add_woocommerce_order_fields', 10, 2);
function add_woocommerce_order_fields($address, $order ) {
    $address['nombrecontacto'] = $order->get_meta('_billing_nombrecontacto');

    return $address;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

**Bonus** - Make the field editable:

```
// Make the custom billing field Editable in Admin order pages
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_billing_fields', 'add_woocommerce_admin_billing_fields');
function add_woocommerce_admin_billing_fields($billing_fields) {
    $billing_fields['nombrecontacto'] = array( 'label' => __('Nombre contacto', 'woocommerce') );

    return $billing_fields;
}
```

[image]

Comment: thankyou @loictheaztec  , the code isn´t working , why if you declare billing_nombrecontacto  later you used {nombrecontacto}  whitout "billing_" ?

Comment: @fakasmile1 So it works now with this little missing function…

Comment: YEAAAAAH , its all right, thanyou of  my fall heart